# Display API result with PHP on my webpage

Tags: php, api, error-handling

I'm trying to display the result of this API in my webpage with PHP.

I don't know what's the issue but currently my code is just not working? (Blank page)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
$nethash = File_get_content("http://mattsmines.net/OMC/get.php?id=nethash");
die("{$nethash}");
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: One thing you may have done before asking your question is to [search the PHP documentation for `File_get_content`.](http://fr2.php.net/results.php?q=File_get_content&l=en&p=all) You would have found out that you mispelled the function name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct(ish) answer is @Mr.Smith answer. but being me id like to add, that using die will stop the output and cause the page not to print the rest of the html.

Also that if the API your accessing got hacked(possible) or goes down(probable) you could expose all your users to what it serves, junking up your page.

And curl is faster over fgc, so perhaps you will find the following code more useful.

```
<?php 
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://mattsmines.net/OMC/get.php?id=nethash',
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 5,
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 5,
    CURLOPT_FAILONERROR => true,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
));
$result = curl_exec($ch);

if(substr($result, -3) == 'h/s'){
    $result = 'Nethash is crunching @ '.htmlentities($result);
}else{
    $result = 'Error fething hash!';
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p><?php echo $result; ?></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Also if you wanted to query multiple ids from the API you can wrap the curl in a function and just pass the id, (I also added a simple session caching so as you wont need to query the API on every page load, which will slow down the request and make your page slow.)

```
<?php 
session_start();

function get_hash($id){
    if(!isset($_SESSION[md5($id)])){
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => 'http://mattsmines.net/OMC/get.php?id='.$id,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 5,
            CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 5,
            CURLOPT_FAILONERROR => true,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
        ));
        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        if(substr($result, -3) == 'h/s'){
            $_SESSION[md5($id)] = htmlentities(ucfirst($id)).' is crunching @ '.htmlentities($result);
        }else{
            $_SESSION[md5($id)] = 'Error fething hash for '.htmlentities($id);
        }
    }
    return $_SESSION[md5($id)];
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <p><?php echo get_hash('nethash'); ?></p>
    <p><?php echo get_hash('some.other.id'); ?></p>
</body>
</html>
```

### Edit (see comments) <kbd>**[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/NRvdoe)**</kbd>:

```
<?php 
session_start();

/**
 * Simple OMC pool API class
 * 
 * @author Lawrence Cherone
 * @version 0.01
 */
class omc{
    public $totalz = array();

    /**
     * Calls API and stores result in $_SESSION
     *
     * @param string $id
     * @return string
     */
    function call_api($id){
        if(!isset($_SESSION[md5($id)])){
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => 'http://mattsmines.net/OMC/get.php?id='.$id,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 5,
            CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 5,
            CURLOPT_FAILONERROR => true,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
            ));
            $_SESSION[md5($id)] = curl_exec($ch);
        }
        return $_SESSION[md5($id)];
    }

    /**
     * Gets current pool hash speed and stores in $this->totalz scope.
     *
     * @param string $id
     * @return int
     */
    function get_pool_hash($id){
        if(!isset($this->totalz[$id])){
            $result = $this->call_api($id);

            if(substr($result, -3) == 'h/s'){
                $this->totalz[$id] = (int) $result;
            }else{
                $this->totalz[$id] = 0;
            }
        }
        return $this->totalz[$id];
    }

    /**
     * Display queried pools as string
     *
     * @return string
     */
    function display(){
        $ret = null;
        foreach($this->totalz as $pool=>$hashrate){
            $ret .= ucfirst($pool).' is crunching @ '.number_format($hashrate).' Mh/s'.'<br>';
        }
        return $ret;
    }

    /**
     * Calculates the queried pools total hash rate and returns string
     *
     * @return string
     */
    function total_rate(){
        return 'Total Hash Rate: '.number_format(array_sum($this->totalz)).' Mh/s';
    }

    /**
     * Query's the total OMC hash rate and returns string
     *
     * @return string
     */
    function total_omc(){
        $result = $this->call_api('totalomc');
        return 'The total OMC volume is currently: '.number_format(htmlentities($result)).' Mh/s';
    }

    /**
     * Get current mining pool difficulty
     *
     * @return string
     */
    function total_diff(){
       $result = $this->call_api('diff');
       return 'The current Omnicoin difficulty is currently: '.number_format(htmlentities($result)).' .';
    }

}
/**
 * Example: 
 * 
 * Initialize the object and query the API, by passing the pool ids
 */
$omc = new omc();
$omc->get_pool_hash('nethash');
$omc->get_pool_hash('OMhash');
$omc->get_pool_hash('BLhash');
$omc->get_pool_hash('MOhash');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <p><?php echo $omc->display(); ?></p>
    <p><?php echo $omc->total_rate();?></p>
    <p><?php echo $omc->total_omc();?></p> 
    <p><?php echo $omc->total_diff();?></p> 
</body>
</html>
```

Also as you want to call the API multiple times you should utilize curl_multi to do all them requests at once, which will speed up the API request. 
<kbd>**[Gist - curl_multi version](https://gist.github.com/lcherone/f5a3d4859c0d11cba868)**</kbd> <kbd>**[In Action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/XWrEX2)**</kbd>

Comment: How would I go about giving the ID's a different text, not displaying the ID just displaying a text? http://prntscr.com/3frawc So for example I could also for the volume ID = "The total OMC volume is currently: XX OMC's"

Comment: change the text in the function to `The total OMC volume is currently:`, ive updated it. you could also change it abit to pass the string to the function to concatenate onto the output.

Comment: Yeah but I want to keep the output like it was for the hashrates, do I need an extra function for the volume then?

Comment: whats the API url for OMC's the current only returns a hash, dont quite get what you mean, ill make changes to best suit. Do you mean all of the hash rates added up?

Comment: This the current volume API http://mattsmines.net/OMC/get.php?id=totalomc, I want to include that too ;)

Comment: I thought I could add those 2 functions just to the code before the editing from you was done again, but it's not working! Code: http://pastebin.com/WzbzFPk1 Where is the fail? Sorry for all the questions.

Comment: np, you had a syntax error `function total_diff() (` should be `function total_diff() {` Ive updated it to include that method.

Comment: @user3598987 also added a curl_multi version check last paragraph ;p enjoy

Comment: Ah thanks man! You are a big help. Is there anyway that the sessionID will timeout and create a new one, or should I add <META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT='60; URL=index.php'> for updating the statistics?

Comment: np, you caught me on a good day ;p, you could make a clear method within the class that clears them ($_SESSION) before doing the request.

Answer (score 3):

**Your `File_get_content` function is wrong it should be `file_get_contents`**
See...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
$nethash = file_get_contents("http://mattsmines.net/OMC/get.php?id=nethash");
die("{$nethash}");
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $nethash = file_get_contents("http://mattsmines.net/OMC/get.php?id=nethash");
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't have enabled errors displaying. If yes, then you can see a message:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function File_get_content() in ...
```

Use this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<?php
$nethash = File_get_contents("http://mattsmines.net/OMC/get.php?id=nethash");
die("{$nethash}");
?>

</body>
</html>
```

You should have enabled displaying errors (`E_ALL`) if you are developing any application (or in development mode/environment).

Comment: Thanks, working great. How would I go about adding a second function? So I can display about 5 API results on one page?

Comment: And if I want to add a second function on the same page, is that even possible?

Comment: I don't understand, what you exactly mean. And why my answer was unaccepted?